# How to handle shell script arguments in heredoc?

Tags: shell

I need to switch to oracle user to change permissions to tnsnames.ora file. I am passing this file path as argument but looks like somewhere the syntax is wrong. Appreciate help in fixing this issue.

Belows is the peice of my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su - oracle <<-"EOF"
    chmod 777 "$1"
EOF
```

It is failing by giving the following error:

```
/home/itsh->./dothis.sh /home/oracle/orasys/11.2.0.2/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
chmod: cannot access `': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Quoting the `EOF` heredoc marker tells the shell *not* to expand the contents of the heredoc. If you want it to do that then you don't want to quote the marker.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. It worked.

Comment: Existing answer only works for trivial cases. If you want to be able to pass arbitrary values through safely, it's more interesting.

Comment: Want to test the security impact of any of these practices? Try running `./yourscript '$(touch /tmp/hello)'`; if it's Done Right, you'll get an error (or permissions changed on a file named `./$(touch /tmp/hello)`, if one exists); done wrong, you'll get a file named `/tmp/hello` created.

Answer (score 1):

The operation of a here document is specified [in the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) where it says:

> If any character in word is quoted, the delimiter shall be formed by performing quote removal on word, and the here-document lines shall not be expanded. Otherwise, the delimiter shall be the word itself.
>
> If no characters in word are quoted, all lines of the here-document shall be expanded for parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. In this case, the `<backslash>` in the input behaves as the `<backslash>` inside double-quotes (see Double-Quotes). However, the double-quote character ( '"' ) shall not be treated specially within a here-document, except when the double-quote appears within "$()", "``", or "${}".

So by using `<<-"EOF"` (instead of `<<-EOF`) as your here document marker you are *explicitly* telling the shell *not* to expand any variables (from the shell context) in the here document contents.

This is often what you want when you are using a heredoc for a shell snippet but in your case this is exactly the opposite of what you appear to be looking for.

Comment: Encouraging practices that lead to shell injection vulnerabilities? Tsk, tsk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did, in passing, indicate that this is often not what one wants to do here but you are certainly correct that your solution is safer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in any way concerned about security, the right thing to do is not to change your quoting, but to keep it as it is and use `bash -s` to pass your arguments to the shell running as the `oracle` user directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u oracle bash -s "$@" <<-'EOF'
    chmod 777 "$1"
EOF
```

...or, if you *must* use `sudo su - oracle` (which I'd argue is bad practice, and best avoided):

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v sudo_cmd '%q ' bash -s "$@"
sudo su - oracle -c "$sudo_cmd" <<-'EOF'
    chmod 777 "$1"
EOF
```

With either of these practices, your inner shell runs the `$1` expansion itself -- and the data on the command line *isn't* substituted into, and parsed as, code.