# Variables in remote SSH session

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting

I have some inconsistent behavior in my bash script. 
There are variables, and all of them have values assigned to them, I confirm them by echoing the values at the beginning of the script.

However, when passing them to a remote SSH session, one variable has value, whereas the other one appear to be blank. I am pretty sure I am not overwriting the variable's value.

```
# Script input arguments
USER=$1
SERVER=$2
# Other vars
PFX=$8
#
ADDRESS=$USER@$SERVER

function run {
    ssh $ADDRESS /bin/bash $@
}

# Script body, some stuff happens here
run << "SSHCONNECTION2"
    sudo mv "/home/$USER/$PFX" "/home/$USER/certs/"
SSHCONNECTION2
```

So, the output of `mv` is

> error 03-Jan-2017 17:20:39    mv: cannot move '/home/admin/' to a subdirectory of itself, '/home/admin/certs/admin'

Can somebody give me a hint what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: When you quote the heredoc sigil, you're telling the local interpreter not to expand any variables in the heredoc.

Comment: ...thus, it's only the *remote* value of `USER`, not the local one, being used.-

Comment: This is actually part of why using all-caps names for your own variables is bad practice: It means you're using the same namespace shared with operating system and shell tools, so you can be unknowingly overwriting (or unknowingly *using*) variables with meaning to other parts of the system.

Comment: See [the POSIX spec on environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), specifying that all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the system, and names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy amazing, I did not know this! Thank you for this useful comment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So if I use lowercase variable names, is there anything else I need to do in SSH session to access the values, e.g. double quotes, escape characters etc?

Comment: Stop quoting the sigil. `<<SSHCONNECTION2`, not `<< "SSHCONNECTION2"`.

Comment: BTW, my answer is going through a fair bit of trouble to do the escaping locally rather than remotely and avoid remote quoting -- this is a place where there's actually security exposure to getting it wrong. Let's say that an attacker figures out a way to introduce an arbitrarily-named certificate into your system; if `pfx=$'$(rm -rf $HOME)\'$(rm -rf $HOME)\''`, then you're going to have a bad day no matter what kinds of quotes you use if *not* going the proper `eval`-safe escaping route.

Comment: BTW, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338964/how-to-handle-shell-script-arguments-in-heredoc -- arguably, this might be a duplicate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it is a similar question, agreed, I searched SSH session rather than heredoc.

Comment: Well -- this is part of why we *like* good duplicates here (ones that are clearly asked and different enough from how existing questions are posed): Someone who has the same problem but doesn't use the right search keywords can end up finding this version rather than the other. From that perspective, something adds value even after being marked a dupe and no longer getting more answers directly.

Comment: Oh, btw -- be sure you quote `"$@"`; as bare `$@`, it behaves the exact same way as `$*` (munging all your arguments into a string, and then splitting and globbing that string back into a list). That's something that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`USER` had a remote value because `USER` *always* has a value: By default, it's the current user account on [all POSIX systems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html). To avoid conflicting with system-defined variable names, you should use lower-case names for your own shell and environment variables (the former because setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable will implicitly overwrite the latter).

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - not /bin/sh; printf %q (thus, eval-safe quoting) is a bash extension

user=$1
pfx=$8

# Tell the shell to quote your variables to be eval-safe!
printf -v user_q '%q' "$user"
printf -v pfx_q '%q' "$pfx"

# ...then you can use those eval-safe version in your heredoc
run << SSHCONNECTION2
    # because the values are self-quoted, don't put their expansions inside quotes
    sudo mv /home/$user_q/$pfx_q /home/$user_q/certs/
SSHCONNECTION2
```

Notes:

- The sigil (`SSHCONNECTION2`) is intentionally unquoted to allow expansions to occur.
- Using lower-case variable names avoids inadvertently conflicting with names meaningful to the shell or system.

---

The above is a bit unfortunate, because the literal contents of the `SSHCONNECTION2` heredoc isn't code that could safely be run directly in a shell. Consider [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32339623/14122).

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try and accept your answer, I am fairly new to bash, and now this makes sense.